# divs hide correctly on page load, but need to show when back button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have several divs that are to be hidden on page load on a html form I am designing. Some contain text fields, some contain dropdown boxes. The are shown based on when certain radio buttons are clicked in the form. I am using javascript to hide the divs.  Here is the code I am using:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 

 function start() {
 hide('hideablearea');
 hide('nontenant');
 hide('conftype');
 hide('rec_roomlayout');
 hide('req_roomlabel');
 hide('req_roomdrpdwn');    
}
window.onload = start;
</script>
```

It works perfectly.  My problem is...when the form is submitted and there is an error (for example, the user forgets to complete a required field) and clicks the back button, this function fires again and hides everything..and I want the hidden divs which have info inthem to show at this point.  Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

K

Comment: You might want to ask yourself why you're forcing the user to click *Back* to correct their errors.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to re-think your design if once you display an error message, the user needs to click *Back* to go to the previous page and correct the information.  The previous page will have no concept of the error message.  I can see two ways to correct this.

**1) Do all error checking in JavaScript**

If you implement your error handling in script, you can immediately inform users of errors and missing information before the page is submitted.  You would then only submit the form if everything checks out.

**2) Re-display the form on post back**

When the user submits the form, you'd do required error checking on the server.  You would then *re-render* the form again, with all the user-entered information, and display error messages.  On this page, you'd write something like:

```
<script>var hasErrors = true;</script>
```

If the page has errors, your client side script could avoid hiding the relevant information.  No-where in this model does the user need to click the *Back* button to correct their mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's responses. I feel I should add that when the form is submitted, an .asp page performs the error checking. If there is an error, a meesasge is displayed and the user is sent back to the page via a hyperlink which displays 'Back'.  The hyperlink performs this action:

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;">Back</a>

Comment: Your design is flawed.  When the user goes *Back*, you lose all context of what the error was.  Your ASP page should render the form again with the error messages displayed, allowing them to correct the issues.

Comment: @Mike..so that hasErrors code would be on the page processing the form?

Comment: You should only have one page.  This page should submit to itself, and validate the input and display errors on POST.

Comment: thanks for the input. This used to be a simple, simple form with no more than 6 or 7 text fields on it total. the asp code to process it has always worked. The user has requested the form to have much more functinality and I'm trying to work with the old asp processing code.  Gonna take a look at this design again.

Comment: This is what's known as [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) - It was a poor design to begin with, now you're trying to modify the code and facing the consequences.  It's often good advice to take the time to fix the root problems, otherwise you'll just waste more and more time on hacking things into working.

Answer (score 0):

You can put id attribute to your divs and then control if your div has a message to show then you didn't hide them.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function start() {
        if (document.getElementById('hideablearea') == "") {
            hide('hideablearea');
        }
        ...
    }
</script>
```